# I am unable to convert numbers extracted from a text field to be considered numeric in SQL

Tags: sql, extract, numeric

I have a field in our SQL DB, labeled result-answer. In this field are results and any notes appended to them. I found a logic to extract the numbers from the field, but I can't convert them to be numeric. We are using Precision BI as our intermediary program.

I am attempting to pull only those with a value less than 7. I have the numbers alone using a string that extracts only the numbers from the fields.

```
Left(SubString([result].[resultanswer], PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', [result].
[resultanswer]), 8000), PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString([result].[resultanswer],
PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', [result].[resultanswer]), 8000) + 'X')-1)
```

However when I add the query to only display those numbers less than 7 I receive a conversion error, most frequently along the lines of 'unable to convert varchar to numeric.' If I run the search without the less than 7 query it will run just fine and only display numbers in this field. If I add a field to show if that field isnumeric it displays 1 or yes for all of them. I can take and convert the values to numeric through a convert function or a cast function (adding convert or cast to the beginning of the above string) , but as soon as I add the less than 7 criteria it says that it can't convert, even though, it did before adding the criteria. The whole thing doesn't make sense.

Here is a sample of the data.

```
result-numericresult    result-resultanswer result-numeric
9.23                    9.23                    9.23
.00                     9.24                    9.24
.00                     9.24 Result Repeated    9.24
.00                     9.25                    9.25
9.25                    9.25                    9.25
```

As you can see I have a result field (called numericresult) that has the numerics already, the problem with it is that the program supplying the data to the DB is sending zeros instead of actual values. I also have a result answer field (called resultanswer), which gives me the numerics, but also has text. The goal was to basically replace the numericresult field with a real numericresult field that doesn't have zeros when it shouldn't. Thus the string to pull the numbers from the resultanswer field. The last column (called numeric) is the custom field that pulls the numbers from the resultanswer field and is the field I am attempting to measure by. So those values less than 7.

I apologize for not including this info in the original post, but we had a bad storm coming and the lights were fickering. So rather than lose what I had, I went ahead and posted.

Comment: maybe a dumb question, but why are you combining them in the same field?  Things would go a lot easier for you if you separated the value from the description....

Comment: Can you show your table structure, sample data and the exact query you are using?

Comment: I agree with Olaf - additionally, what DMBS are you using?

Comment: Er, DBMS. Edit time ran out. Solutions may vary depending on your implementation, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CAST(value AS int)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Or you could `CAST` as `decimal(x,y)` if you prefer.

Once you've made it numeric, you can perform numeric operations and comparisons on it. 
Note though that if you `CAST` some non-numeric value the query will fail.

Comment: It won't convert to Integer at all, and I have tried performing the cast as decimal, numeric, float, etc. It will convert the field to decimal, numeric, but when it comes to searching for those less than 7 it acts like it hasn't done the conversion and cannot.

Comment: @ThaddeusTG: What do you mean? Could you show us what your filtering condition looks like? I'm sure something like `CAST([result].[numeric] AS decimal(10,2)) < 7` should work.

Comment: I found the problem. In broadening the seach to all result numbers pulled out of result answer I found results that had '%...%', %#-#% and other things that are not and cannot be numeric. In doing that I realized that it was not applying the rest of the search criteria before attempting to do the conversion which created the error. I went in and added the other criteria i.e. case when (blah blah) then cast as numeric, and it worked.